# Retroactive benefit for a Gentile's chametz?

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven

Some credit card companies offer a cash bonus for store purchases.

Let's say Mincha has a live-in Gentile worker, Jim. Jim is an authorized credit card user for Mincha's account. During Pesach, Jim buys lots of chametz and charges it.

In June, Chase bank, gives Mincha $200 in cash back bonus for all the chametz that Jim bought several months ago.

Even though Mincha didn't get the bonus immediately during Pesach, did he derive any benefit from the chametz that, he paid for?

Comment: How is Jim allowed to buy the Chametz on Mincha's credit card during Pesach??

Comment: @DoubleAA - He has his own credit card with Mincha's account #. I prob. meant to say authorized "user".

Comment: I meant allowed Halachically. Mincha is gifting chametz to a non-jew on pesach. Sounds like benefit.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Not sure. How is that different from giving Jim cash and telling him, go buy what you want?

Comment: Well, in this case, Mincha is the one paying for the chametz from the store.

Comment: @Daniel - Not sure, based on above cash scenario. What difference does it make if Micha gives Jim cash to buy chametz or Mincha goes with Jim to the store, has Jim buy chametz and Mincha hands the cashier cash, there? How about if they both buy stuff - Mincha's Pesach stuff & Jim's chametz, it goes on the same conveyor, Mincha pays cash, but each person requests the bagger to separate their stuff in their own bags and each person carries his own stuff? Or does Mincha have to give Jim the money so Jim can give it to the cashier?

Comment: Technically, the cash back "bonus" is merely a discount on the price of purchase - an incentivization to buy - which is more than made up by the interest charges in the vast majority of cases. Assuming Jim owes his employer for the charges he makes on the card for personal use, then it's just an open line of credit between Jim and the CC company for which Mincha is the party responsible to ensure payment. The points could be considered interest earned on his "loan" to Jim...